# Converting pandas series object to int in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I started my machine learning journey by deciding to explore recommender systems so that I can apply it in some of the projects for my company. Now, I am using Pandas for data analysis. The data set is the imdv movies data set. Here, I am trying to convert a pandas series object to `int` but it converts the series to `float64`.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

'`clean_ids`' is the method that I am using to do this and you can see that '`id`' changes to `float64`. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct. The problem is that you have NaN values in your `id` column and python interprets NaN as float. In your code any decimal values it encounters will be converted to integer but represented as $x.0$ due to presence on NaN values. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558973/why-is-nan-considered-as-a-float) for more.

As for a solution to your problem you can either drop the NaN values or use [IntegerArray](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) from pandas. It is currently experimental but suits yor problem.